# npm run dev providing errno2 "no such file or directory"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, vite

So I am in the middle of learning React and I am following a tutorial. I created a vite file, run in react using TS. When I try to run the dev browser from the terminal in VS Code I get the following error. I have tried multiple times and can't seem to find the problem. Any help would be awesome! Thanks!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUStI.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

you are running the command a folder above the project, run the command in the root of the project.

you are running the command a folder above the project, run the command in the root of the project.

in folder `react-app-tutorial` is your `package.json` which contains the `dev` script

```bash
$ cd react-app-tutorial
```

after

```bash
$ npm run dev
```